# Using DynamicNode and need a lifecycle hook to run after all tests have completed

Tags: junit5

I'm using `DynamicNode` very successfully in a framework that dynamically generates tests and executes them.

Now I have a need to execute some code after all `DynamicNode` collections have executed. This can mean that I have a single JUnit5 class with multiple methods that return `Iterable<DynamicNode>`, but I want to run something only after all the test methods have completed.

Is there a way to do this automatically ?

EDIT: ideally I would like my framework to inject the code to be executed automatically, without the user needing to add a `@AfterAll` annotation on a method and write some extra code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each method that is annotated with `@TestFactory` takes part in the default lifecycle. That means in your case an `@AfterAll` annotated method should do the trick.

> **`@AfterAll`**
>
> Denotes that the annotated method should be executed after all
>   `@Test`, `@RepeatedTest`, `@ParameterizedTest`, and `@TestFactory`
>   methods in the current class; analogous to JUnit 4’s `@AfterClass`.
>   Such methods are inherited (unless they are hidden or overridden) and
>   must be static (unless the "per-class" test instance lifecycle is
>   used).

Copied from https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-annotations

Comment: thanks, I edited my question - is there a way to not require the user to add the `@AfterAll` annotation and write code, maybe there is a way for my `DynamicNode` iterator implementation to tell JUnit that some code has to be executed on shutdown ?

Comment: Do you have already an extension that your users apply to a test class? Perhaps https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/AfterAllCallback.html is the right tool then.

Comment: no, this is purely `DynamicNode` based. finally I am going with a very dirty JVM shutdown hook approach, but for local unit testing, I hope this is fine: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/develop/karate-junit5/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/junit5/Karate.java